# Best approach to sync multiple clients with server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014, database-administration, data-synchronization

I am working on an application which will run on 5 different machine. Data of each machine will be stored on the same machine. I have to sync data of all machine with a centralized database. I am unable to find answer to this question: What will be the best approach for this?

1. On Each machine a schedule sql job will sync the data with centralized server
2. Server will request each machine to sync the data

Kindly advice with advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure sql server to use replication and publish a replica to each of the 5 machines.

You have to evaluate if you need all changes in all machines if yes you need merge replication, they have other structures and options such as filters to only have specific data in your remote machines.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has solved this problem for you - they have developed the [Sync framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Sync_Framework). I used this around 4 years ago, and it was rather good - but as @Juan says in his comment, it's now no longer actively developed by Microsoft, and the Open Source version seems to be pretty quiet.

There are two obvious options.

You can use (merge) replication if you want to solve this as a database issue. This is the simplest solution - replication simply copies the data from your clients to the target database, and Microsoft deals with all the scheduling, conflict resolution etc.

However, often there is some data or business logic between the clients - a common problem is that there may be a conflict between primary keys or lookup values between your clients. For instance, if you're using integers for your primary keys, and machine 1 and machine 2 both assign "1000" as the primary key for a record in the "sales" table, replication becomes tricky. 
Another common scenario is that there is some business logic that must be enforced which is simple on a single machine, but hard when dealing with multiple occasionally connected machines. For instance, if a customer places an order, the application may want to check that the total order value doesn't exceed the customer's credit limit - but what if there is another transaction pending on a separate client?

In those cases, you may want to create a service-oriented synchronization design.
Microsoft provided [WCF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for this. Whilst more flexible, it's probably much more effort to implement. In this model, you probably treat the local database on your clients as a cache, and you push messages to the central machine to reflect user interaction.

Comment: This framework is no longer updated, I used some years ago and it works but it is very difficult to make it works and to update the database schema after the first provision. Replication using the configuration tools from sql is a more robust option.